# Clojure: IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer

Tags: clojure

I have two lists:

```
(def xxa ["olp" "xyz"])
(def xxb ["ulove" "alove" "holp" "sholp"])
```

and a function trying to get the elements of the 1st list that are parts of elements of the 2nd list:

```
(defn in-array
  [array1 array2]
  (for [s1 array1 :when (some #(.contains %1 s1) array2)] s1))
```

(in-array xxa xxb) should return ["olp"]

but I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer  clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke
```

I don't understand what that means. Can someone gives me some light?

Comment: If I run this in a REPL it returns `("olp")` - the error alomst certainly means (if you are also runnig in a REPL) that some other definition is causing the error.

Comment: I'm running this with "Counterclockwise". I have only the five lines of code above and a 6th line with : "(print (in-array(xxa xxb)))" or "(in-array(xxa xxb))".

Comment: If that is your code then you are passing your vectors to `in-array` incorrectly. Try removing the parentheses around them like so: `(in-array xxa xxb)`

Comment: I am not familiar with "Counterclockwise" but I have just tried it in the REPL in "nightcode" 0.4.7 and I get the result you expect! And, as @sp3ctum points out, in your original code you had `(in-array xxa xxb)` and in your comment `(in-array (xxa xxb))`.

Comment: In the second form above `(in-array (xxa xxb))`, Clojure is attempting to call `xxa` as function - which it can, arrays are functions of their indices, but those indices must be integers (hence the error), which `xxb` is not - try `(xxa 1)` to see that in action.

Comment: Yes, (in-array xxa xxb) is correct! With Clojure one likes parentheses but too many is too many!-)

Comment: Cool, gald we got there! And indeed, too many is too many! But Clojure, so far as I've found, only uses exactly as many as it needs - they are there for a reason!

Answer (score 10):

Here's an attempt to make the discussion above into a clear answer for those who come along later. If I've missed something please let me know or edit:

Starting with the original example:

```
user> (def xxa ["olp" "xyz"])
#'user/xxa
user> (def xxb ["ulove" "alove" "holp" "sholp"])
#'user/xxb
user> (defn in-array [array1 array2]
        (for [s1 array1 :when (some #(.contains %1 s1) array2)] s1))
#'user/in-array
```

And then as peter points out, an extra set of `()` would cause this error:

```
user> (in-array (xxa xxb))
IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer  clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke (APersistentVector.java:284)
```

Which contains more code than is required to show the situation, so we can trim it down to:

```
user> (xxa xxb)
IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer  clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke (APersistentVector.java:284)
```

which is a minimal case to show the problem. If we change this example to pass the expected type we can see that vectors, when called as a function, take a number and look that number up in themselves.

```
user> (xxa 1)
"xyz"
```

So finally we can correct the call and get the expected output, almost exactly:

```
user> (in-array xxa xxb)
("olp")
```

The result is a (lazy) sequence from the `for` expression and user3166747 had asked for a vector (non lazy, and random access) which we can get by adding a call to `vec`:

```
user> (defn in-array [array1 array2]
        (vec (for [s1 array1 :when (some #(.contains %1 s1) array2)] s1)))
#'user/in-array

user> (in-array xxa xxb)
["olp"]
```

and now it matches exactly.